# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when loading JS file

Tags: javascript, ajax

Our site, www.mysite.com (for example), uses ajax to interact with a secondary application that sits on a sub-domain (service.mysite.com). There is small library of functions which manage theses interaction in file called scripts.js that sits in the sub-domain. The link to this file is placed in the HTML of the main site like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://service.mysite.com/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

Our site and it's subdomains are hosted in a small farm that is load balanced by ARR and all applications are built in .net and hosted on windows servers. This works perfectly for 90% of users however it seems a small number of users get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET     scripts.js
```

It's my understanding this is likely due the configuration of their browser settings, however I can't really ask our customers to reconfigure their browsers to support our site. Is there anything I can do from my side to stop this from happening? Could it be related to how our site is load balanced?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?